# Calculate the likely number of distinct categorical values (diagnoses) for a patient population

Tags: probability

In healthcare, patient diagnosis is recorded with a code called an ICD code. There are around 43K distinct diagnosis codes. So, basically any population can have between 0 and 43K DISTINCT diagnosis. To keep things simple, assuming that:

1. Every diagnosis is equally likely
2. Each patient has just 1 diagnosis

... how do I estimate the number of distinct diagnoses in a patient population of N?

Comment: This sounds like the same setting as the [Coupon collector's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is related to the Coupon collector's problem as noted in the comments.

Building off of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/693254/697491) post, the probability of observing $k$ unique letters in $m$ random uniform samples from an alphabet of size $n$ is:

$$\bigg\{\!{m\!\atop{k}}\bigg\}\binom{n}{k}\frac{k!}{n^m}=\bigg\{\!{m\!\atop{k}}\bigg\}\frac{n!}{n^m(n-k)!}$$

Where $\big\{\!{m\!\atop{k}}\big\}$ is the Stirling number of the second kind.

For large $m$, $\big\{\!{m\!\atop{k}}\big\}$ can be [approximated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind#Asymptotic_approximation) ([original paper](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/301651745.pdf)):

$$\left\{{n \atop k}\right\} \sim \sqrt{\frac{v-1}{v(1-G)}} \left(\frac{v-1}{v-G}\right)^{n-k} \frac{k^n}{n^k} e^{k(1-G)} \left({n \atop k}\right)$$

where $v=n/k$, and $G\in(0,1)$ is the unique solution to $G=ve^{G-v}$.

Here is an R function that returns the probability of every $k$:

```
library(copula)

coupons1 <- function(n, m) {
  l <- min(m, n)
  k <- 1:l
  if (m < 200) {
    logS <- log(Stirling2.all(m)[k])
  } else {
    # estimate the log Stirling numbers
    v <- m/k
    G <- 1/v
    vexpv <- v/exp(v)
    for (i in 1:5) G <- G - (G - (vexpG <- vexpv*exp(G)))/(1 - vexpG) # Newton-Raphson
    logS <- (log(v - 1) - log(v*(1 - G)))/2 +
      (m - k)*(log(v - 1) - log(v - G)) + m*log(k) - k*log(m) + k*(1 - G) +
      lgamma(m + 1) - lgamma(k + 1) - lgamma(m - k + 1)
    if (l == m) logS[m] <- 0
  }
  pmf <- exp(logS + lgamma(n + 1) - lgamma(n - k + 1) - m*log(n))
  pmf/sum(pmf)
}
```

The probability of $k=1,2...43000$ for $n=m=43000$:

```
system.time(k1 <- coupons1(43e3, 43e3))
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>    0.02    0.00    0.01

plot(26900:27500, k1[26900:27500], xlab = "k", ylab = "p(k)", col = "blue")
```

[image]

Comparing that result to a brute-force approach:

```
Rcpp::cppFunction("
  NumericVector coupons2(const int& n, const int& m) {
    int maxk;
    int n1 = n - 1;
    if (n > m) {
      maxk = m;
    } else {
      maxk = n;
    }
    
    NumericVector k (maxk);
    k(0) = 1;
    
    for (int i = 1; i < maxk; i++) {
      for (int j = i; j > 0; j--) {
        k(j) = (k(j - 1)*(n - j) + k(j)*(j + 1))/n;
      }
      k(0) = k(0)/n;
    }
    
    for (int i = maxk; i < m; i++) {
      for (int j = n1; j > 0; j--) {
        k(j) = (k(j - 1)*(n - j) + k(j)*(j + 1))/n;
      }
      k(0) = k(0)/n;
    }
    
    return k;
  }
")

system.time(k2 <- coupons2(43e3, 43e3))
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>   12.29    0.00   12.31
```

The relative error from using the Stirling number approximation is small for a large $m$.

```
max(abs(k1[26900:27500] - k2[26900:27500])/k2[26900:27500])
#> [1] 8.288009e-07

points(26900:27500, k2[26900:27500], col = "orange", pch = 20)
legend("topright", legend = c("k1", "k2"), col = c("blue", "orange"), pch = c(1, 20))
```

[image]

### A note on the `occupancy` R package:

The `occupancy` package features the distribution for this problem, with an option for exact or approximate calculations. `docc` returns the PMF of `k`. However, it is much slower than `coupons1` and `coupons2` above, with the computation time growing approximately geometrically for $m=n$. Additionally, the approximation provided is poor compared to the one provided by `coupons1`:

```
n <- 43e3L
system.time(k3 <- occupancy::docc(1:n, n, n, approx = TRUE))
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>    1.61    2.00    3.61
max(abs(k3[26900:27500] - k2[26900:27500])/k2[26900:27500])
#> [1] 0.01156602
```

Time `occupancy::docc` for $m=n=4300$ with `approx = FALSE`:

```
n <- 4300L
system.time(occupancy::docc(1:n, n, n))
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>   35.58    0.14   35.75
```

Comment: Very interested analysis (+1).  (Noteable here that the ```docc``` function uses the normal approximation to the occupancy distribution when ```approx = TRUE```.)

Comment: That's what I was suspecting based on the abstract to the paper referenced in the package documentation. Temme's approximation is surprisingly good and tends to converge quickly, so the key for the speedup was vectorizing over Newton's method for each value of `G`. A further improvement could be a vectorized check on convergence instead of the hard-coded 5 iterations.

Comment: Yeah, I think there are two take-aways from this analysis: (1) C++ is much faster than R for recursive computations; and (2) Temme's approximation is better than the normal approximation for the occupancy distribution.