# $n$ people each randomly assigned a number from $1$ to $m$ with replacement. Probability that exactly one number is assigned to more than one person?

Tags: probability, self-study, combinatorics

Suppose that $n$ people are each randomly assigned a number from $1$ to $m$ with replacement.  What is the probability that exactly one number is assigned to more than one person?

What I have tried:

Defining the event $A$ to be 'exactly one number is assigned to more than one person', I can see that the probability of $A$ is $0$ when $m=n$ and $1$ when $m<n$.
For $m>n$, the sample space would be $m^n$. I have written out the sample space for $n=3$ and $m=4$. In this case, $P(A)=40/64=5/8$. However, I cannot see how to compute the number of sample points in the general case.

Comment: It seems to be a homework, so you should add `[self-study]` tag and tell us what have you tried, where are you stuck, and what help you need.

Comment: @Tim Thanks, I've added your suggestions

Comment: The probability of $A$ is not $0$ when $m=n$; consider $m=n=3$, with assignments $(1,1,2)$.  It is also not $1$ when $m < n$; consider $m=3, n=4$ with assignments $(1,1,2,2)$.

Comment: See this related question on the occupancy statistic https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/605146/deterministic-formula-for-average-number-of-unique-items-picked/605209#605209

Comment: @jbowman ah I see my error was only checking cases where m=1

Comment: @YashaswiMohanty Thanks, I think that is what I needed.  By the top voted response from that article, assuming n >= 1, P(A) would be 1/m^n-1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sample space is
\begin{align}
\Omega = \{(N_1, N_2, \ldots, N_n): N_i \in \{1, \ldots, m\}, 1 \leq i \leq n\}. 
\end{align}
Clearly, $|\Omega| = m^n$.

To determine the probability of interest $P(A) = |A|/|\Omega|$, it suffices to count $|A|$.  **Suppose $m \geq n$**.  Note that if $k \in \{1, \ldots, m\}$ is the "exactly one number" that is assigned to more than one person, then $k$ can be assigned to $2, 3, \ldots, n$ people.  In view of this, $|A|$ can be then determined by applying the rule of product and the rule of sum.

In detail, there are $\binom{m}{1}$ ways of choosing $k$ that will be assigned to $j$ ($2 \leq j \leq n$) people.  Once $k$ is chosen, there are $\binom{n}{j}$ ways to assign it to $j$ people picked randomly from a cohort of $n$ people, and $\binom{m - 1}{n - j} \times (n - j)!$ ways of assigning the remaining $n - j$ people each a distinct number. It then follows by the rule of product that the number of ways of assigning exactly one number to $j$ people ($2 \leq j \leq n$) is:
\begin{align}
\binom{m}{1} \times \binom{n}{j} \times \binom{m - 1}{n - j} \times (n - j)!.
\end{align}

By the rule of sum:
\begin{align}
|A| = \binom{m}{1}\sum_{j = 2}^n \binom{n}{j}\binom{m - 1}{n - j}(n - j)!.
\end{align}

I am not sure though, if $|A|$ can be further simplified.