# Urn problem. How to calculate this probability?

Tags: probability

Drawing n times from an urn that has m unique elements. Drawing one at a time, with replacement. What is the probability that resampling happens during a draw on average?

Clarification: The first draw has probability 0 of resampling. The second draw has probability 1/m of resampling. For further draws, it gets more complicated, because it matters whether and how often resampling happened during the previous draws.

I am interested in the average probability of resampling over n draws. In effect, I want to count the number of resamples in n draws and divide by n.

Comment: Could you please explain the distinction you are implying between "probability" and "average probability"?

Comment: Which draw? This matters sine in the first draw there is 0 chance of resampling. Or are you asking what is the probability of getting "at least one resample during n draws"?

Comment: I understood the question as the second thing you wrote: at least one resample during n draws. But Dav should better specify what he needs.

Comment: @LevG agreed.  Please note your interpretation of this question already has answers in many posts here on CV, because it is easily answered by counting samples with and without replacement.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I edited the question. @LevG I am not interested in "at least one resample during n draws", rather counting the number of resamples in n draws and dividing it by n.

Comment: "Counting the number of resamples ... and divid[ing] by n" doesn't compute a probability: it computes an *expectation.* The difference becomes obvious when you consider the case where $n$ exceeds $m+1$: the probability of at least one resample is $1$ (that's implied by Pigeonhole Principle) while the expected number of resamples must exceed $1$ (by the extended Pigeonhole Principle).  So: which quantity are you looking for?

Comment: @DavBhaji, see [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/588069/214015). It deals with the distribution of the number of unique elements drawn ($k$ in the link). From that, it is straightforward to get the distribution of the number of resamples by subtracting $k$ from the number of samples (i.e., $m-k$ in the link).